# Infinite summation with complex exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

Is there any closed form expression of the following ?
\begin{equation}
 g(n,m) 
 =
 \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty}
 f(k)
 f^*(k+n)
 \exp(j 2 \pi m k )
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 f(k) 
 =
 \sum\limits_{l = 1}^L
 \exp( j \frac{\pi}{N} (2 q_l k + l k^2)) 
\end{equation}
and $f^*$ is the complex conjugate of $f$, and $q_l$ are integers between $0$ and $N-1$.
I tried plugging in the expressions for $L = 1$, which i see some ratios of sinc appearing, but i couldn't manage to make it work for general $L$.